# Random edits and scrambling in Messages

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, messages, big-sur, monterey

I have a problem that appears frequently but not consistently: When I am writing a long message in Messages and edit what I am typing, by deleting and/or inserting a word or phrase, Messages starts cutting off random words in my text and replacing them with apostrophes. Sometimes it also inserts words from one part of my text into another part of the text. I have not seen this happen in any other app. I had this problem first when using Big Sur on a MacBook Air. I recently got a new MacBook and upgraded to Monterey, and the same problem still happens. I found another thread on this same topic, describing exactly the situation I am dealing with in Apple Community (https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253575075), which suggests to me that I am not the only person experiencing this, but no solutions were offered.  Has anyone who has experienced this found a solution?